# String cutting in Unix

Tags: text-processing

How could I transform this text?

Input file format:

```
MOD MAXT:TID=TID190,MT=VCU,MAXT=100;
```

Desired output format:

```
MOD MAXT:TID,MT,MAXT
MOD MAXT:TID190,VCU,100;
```

Comment: You can use,  cat <filename> | sed 's/\([^:]*\).\([^=]*\).\([^,]*\).\([^=]*\).\([^,]*\).\([^=]*\).\([^,]*\).*/\1:\2,\4,\6\n\1:\3,\5,\7/'

Comment: @AVJ no need for the cat, I believe. `sed 's/([^:]*).([^=]*).([^,]*).([^=]*).([^,]*).([^=]*).([^,]*).*/\1:\2‌​,\4,\6\n\1:\3,\5,\7/' <filename>`; However, I had to escape the `()` with `\(\)` for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
sed 'h;s/=[^,]*//gp;g;s/[^:,=]*=//g' <in >out
```

---

```
MOD MAXT:TID,MT,MAXT
MOD MAXT:TID190,VCU,100;
```

Comment: You need to remove the TID= from front, maybe like: `sed 'h;s/=[^,]*//gp;g;s/\([,:]\)[^=]*=/\1/g'`

Comment: @Dani_l - thank you. I didn't even notice.

Comment: @NayotTientong If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

`awk -F':|,|=' '{print $1":"$2","$4","$6"\n"$1":"$3","$5","$7}' FILE`

I use the "|" as OR for the FS, so basically awk separates the line into multiple components (tokens) using either ":" or "," or "=".
Now I can print any part of the line in any order, just needed to insert "\n" as newline to add the 2nd line.

`awk -F':|,|=' '{print $1":"$2","$4","$6"\n"$1":"$3","$5","$7}' <<< 'MOD MAXT:TID=TID190,MT=VCU,MAXT=100;'
MOD MAXT:TID,MT,MAXT
MOD MAXT:TID190,VCU,100;`

Answer (score 0):

Perlishly:

```
perl -ne 'print /(.*:)/, join (",", /(\w+)=/g),"\n", /(.*:)/, join(",", /=([\w;]+)/g),"\n";'
```

We use the default pattern match (e.g. current line) and select capture groups via regex. (Which are then printed)

Gives:

```
MOD MAXT:TID,MT,MAXT
MOD MAXT:TID190,VCU,100;
```